# How to create vuetify datatable with rearranging columns?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I am working on the VueJs template and I need to create a data table with rearranging columns. I get the [Codepen](https://codepen.io/demoapp456/pen/JjjywWP) with rearranging columns but when I added select boxes with this it creates issues and the table is invisible at some point when rearranging columns again agian. I added this method to sort the headers I think it creates conflicts

```
sortTheHeadersAndUpdateTheKey(evt) {
   const headersTmp = this.headers;
   const oldIndex = evt.oldIndex;
   const newIndex = evt.newIndex;
   if (newIndex >= headersTmp.length) {
     let k = newIndex - headersTmp.length + 1;
     while (k--) {
       headersTmp.push(undefined);
     }
   }
   headersTmp.splice(newIndex, 0, headersTmp.splice(oldIndex, 1)[0]);
   this.table = headersTmp;
   this.anIncreasingNumber += 1;
}
```

I created the [New Codepen](https://codepen.io/demoapp456/pen/jOOLvZp) with select boxes. so how can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

As per the above code, the table is invisible at some point due to evt value doesn't have old and new index, **Instead it has old and new position**

> Need to refactor the existing function by decrementing the position
>   values to get the index, so we don't need while loop to add a new
>   index

```
sortTheHeadersAndUpdateTheKey(evt) {
      const headersTmp = this.headers;
      const oldIndex = evt.oldIndex - 1;
      const newIndex = evt.newIndex - 1;
      headersTmp.splice(newIndex, 0, headersTmp.splice(oldIndex, 1)[0]);
      this.table = headersTmp;
      this.anIncreasingNumber += 1;
    },
```

Working codepen here: https://codepen.io/chansv/pen/MWWvPOw?editors=1010